# Decompile .pyc file into script for Python 3.2

Tags: python

I want to decompile a .pyc file into a script file for Python 3.2. All I could find is that they have successfully developed a decompiler for Python 2.7. Is there a tool that could decompile a .pyc file into a regular `.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [unpyc3](http://code.google.com/p/unpyc3/) which is the only one at the moment for 3.2

Comment: Accidentally deleted a .py file before committing it, but I still had the .pyc version. unpyc3 worked perfectly and helped me restore the source with very minimal manual editing!

Answer (score 1):

[uncompyle6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=uncompyle6&:action=display) can decompyle both python 3.x including 3.2 as well as Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

use https://python-decompiler.com/ to decompile .pyc files to .py online